# Extract data from file into vectors but avoid duplicates

Tags: c++, vector, file-read

I want to read data in files that are formatted like:

```
Point1, [3, 4]
```

I'm using delimiters '[' ']' and ',' and replace them with ' ' (empty space).  My code now is fine and working.  But the problem is, if `Point1, [3, 4]` appeared once, I want it to be unique and not to appear again if the same data in the text file exist.

Here is what I have:

```
string line, name;
char filename[50];
int x,y;

cout << "Please enter filename : ";
cin >> filename;

ifstream myfile(filename);
if (myfile.is_open()) {
    while ( myfile.good() ) {
        getline(myfile, line);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i) {
            if (line[i] == '[' || line[i] == ']' || line[i] == ',') {
                line[i] = ' ';
            }
            istringstream in(line);
            in >> name >> x >> y;                                  
        }
        cout <<name <<endl;

        if (name=="Point") {
            p.push_back(Point(x,y));         
        }                          
        count++;
    }    
    myfile.close();
    cout << count;
}
else cout<< "Unable to open file";
```

How do i do this? I tried adding this after `if(name=="Point")`

```
for (int j=0; j<p.size(); j++) {
    if(p.getX != x && p.getY) != y) {
        p.push_back(Point(x,y))
    }
}
```

...but this is not working properly as data was not stored into the vector.

Anyone can help?

Comment: You should reindent your code and btw, I think in your second code section, there is a paranthese too much behind `p.getY`

Comment: Do you need to store the elements in the order as they appear in the file - or it can be stored in any order. If second is true - then use answer with `std::set` - if not then some a little more complicated solution is needed...

Comment: there would be a function to sort orders. so its fine with set i guess. thanks !

Comment: Using a fixed size like "50" for the length of a character array used as a string is a bad practice.  C++'s `std::string` can grow to accomodate input, and there's not a good reason to make your program crash on 50-character strings...if you need to pass a C-style char* string use the `.c_str()` method.  *Also...as noted, please try to get your question formatted more conventionally.  I did this for you in this case, but before you post, there is a preview you can scroll down to and see what your question is going to look like...make sure it looks at least semi-reasonable before you submit!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of storing your data into `vectors` you can store it into `sets`. A set contains only unique values, so you don't have to check the uniqueness of your `Points`, the `set` will manage that.

Instead of defining `vector<Point>`, you have to define `set<Point>`, and instead of using `p.push_back` to add points into your vector, you have to use `p.insert` if it is a `set`.

You can check the `set` documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/).

Comment: What if OP wants to keep the order of points in the file in the container?

Comment: @alestanis p[i].getX and p[i].getY cant be used anymore? I get some operator [] error.

Comment: @RusydiRusydii No, a set doesn't have indexes. You can use an iterator instead. And be careful with your functions, `getX` and `getY` are functions so you should call `myPoint.getX()` and not `myPoint.getX`

Comment: @alestanis In this way, how would I know which one is X and which one is Y for iterator. hmm.

Comment: @RusydiRusydii An iterator points to an element of the set, to a `Point`, not to `x` or `y`. Check the link I put in the answer, and read entries for `begin` and `end`. Take a look at their examples

Comment: @alestanis It was a bit confusing. I did set<Point> mypoints in main(). After that I did mypoints.insert(x,y) but i got an error. Error : invalid type argument of 'unary *' and also some std::set errors.

Comment: @RusydiRusydii You have to instert a **POINT** into your set, not coordinates. `mypoints.insert(Point(x, y))`. You should read the documentation.

Comment: @alestanis I did mypoints.insert(Point(x,y)). Previous post was some typo. There is now errors from stl_function.h, stl_tree.h:980, stl_set.h:307 which is regarding std::pair. and also error for no match for 'operator' in'__x<_y'

Comment: Getting stuck here for pretty long. Sigh

Comment: @RusydiRusydii I'm having a hard time imagining what your error could be without seeing code and the whole error message... Maybe you should post a new question, or send me the full error message and the lines where you see the message

Comment: @alestanis hmm how do i send you

Comment: @RusydiRusydii Post it here :)

Comment: @alestanis i posted it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361423/c-errors-while-using-set

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep you data store in a `std::vector<Point>` you could just check that no corresponding point already exists. Assuming there is an equality operator defined, it is as easy as this:

```
if (p.end() == std::find(p.begin(), p.end(), Point(x, y))) {
    p.push_back(Point(x, y));
}
```

If you `Point` type doesn't have an equality operator and shouldn't get one, you can use a function object together with `find_if()` instead, e.g.:

```
if (p.end() == std::find_if(p.begin(), p.end(),
                      [=](Point const& v) { return x == v.x && y == v.y; })) {
    ...
```

You should separate your loops from other operations: The loop you propose to check if the point already exists is basically what `std::find()` does except that you insert a new point in each iteration! You first want to go through all existing points and see if it exists anywhere. Only if it does not, you'd insert a new point.

Note, that you did a similar mistake when replacing characters in your string: you try to decode the string after checking each character. This isn't so much a semantic problem but it is a major performance problem. You should replace the characters in a loop and **after** that loop you should decode the string just once. Of course, when decoding the string you need to check if the format was OK as it is **always** necessary to determine if an input operation was successful. That is, after your loop replacing the characters you want something like:

```
std::istringstream in(line);
if (in >> name >> x >> y) {
    // now process the data
}
```

... or, if you are like me and don't like naming things which are only around temporarily:

```
if (std::istringstream(line) >> std::ws >> name >> x >> y) {
```

As another note: checking a stream for `good()` is generally the wrong thing to do because a stream can be in perfectly good conditions except that it had seen EOF at some point and, thus, as set the `std::ios_base::eofbit`. More importantly, you need to check **after** the input operation, not before! That is, your first loop should start with something like this:

```
while (std::getline(myFile, line)) {
    ...
```

Comment: There's problem when i tried the first two codes. First one was some instantiated problem. Is there any simple example i could refer to?

Comment: I am getting this error. stl_algo.h 327: instantiated from '_InputIteratorst::find(_InputIterator,_InputIterator, const_Tp&)(with _InputIterator = ___gnu_cxx: .........

Comment: @RusydiRusydii: When you use `std::find()` with a type, it is necessary that the type is *EqualityComparable*, i.e., you need to define operator `operator==()` and `operator!=()` for the type, e.g., `bool operator== (Point const& p0, Point const& p1) { return p0.x == p1.x && p0.y == p1.y; }` and likewise for inequality. Alternatively, you can use a comparison function. This is what the second example does, using C++ 2011 lambda functions (you might need to turn on C++ 2011 with a flag depending on the compiler).

Comment: I inputed that operator for == and !=. Getting the error 'bool point::operator==(const Point&, const Point&)' must take exactly one argument

Comment: @RusydiRusydii: The operator version I wrote is a non-member function. If you want to implement `operator==()` it takes just one argument and is declared something like this: `bool operator== (Point const&) const;`.

Comment: Should I be implementing that in my Point class? I need to do that in order to use getX() and getY() from my Point class right?

Comment: If you have publically accessible operators you should probably implement the operators as free-standing operators (i.e. outside the class but within the same namespace if the class is in a namespace). You need to do a bit research yourself, too! I gave you all the ingredients.

Comment: Try my best looking at every possible reference online. So I gave up on the first code but proceeded to figure out the second on which is          if (p.end() == find_if(p.begin(), p.end(),[=] (Point const& v) { return x == v.x && y == v.y; })) 
         {
          p.push_back(Point(x,y));
         } May I know what is the [=] for? I am getting errors expected primary-expressfrom before [, =, ] and const. When I remove [=] , it just expecting primary expression from const. Please help :(

Comment: The `[=]` introduces a C++ 2011 lambda function with capturing variables from the context by value. It is roughly equivalent to a function object: `struct C { C(int x, int y): x_(x), y_(y) {} bool operator()(Point const& p) const { return x_ == p.x && y_ == p.y; } int x_; int y_; };` The other variants should work, too, though. What did you try and how doesn't it work?

Comment: I don't think quincy 2005 has that C++ 2011 Lambda function. I am currently using bool operator== (Point const&) const; bool operator!= (Point const&) const; in my Point.h and also using the first code you gave to me. Everything compile and was fine. Then I started building the program it came out errors like undefined reference to 'Point::operator==(Point const&) const. It is pointing to other things that I used '==' with. This is weird.